# Route attribute not working for HttpPost in Web Api (404 not found)

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, controller, http-post

In `.NET Web API` I've got a controller with an `[HttpPost]` method. I've tried to distinguish its route via a `[Route]` attribute using 5 dummy parameters. Data itself will be sent and received in via `[FromBody]`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using api.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;    

...
//POST
[Route("api/myControllerPath/p_dummyParam1/p_dummyParam2/p_dummyParam3/p_dummyParam4/p_dummyParam5")]
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> doStuff
            (
              string p_dummyParam1
            , string p_dummyParam2
            , string p_dummyParam3
            , string p_dummyParam4
            , string p_dummyParam5
            , [FromBody] List<int> IDs
            )
        {
            List<int> listIDs;       
                    listIDs = IDs;    
                    return Ok();       
        }
```

However, this path is failing with 404 'Not Found', despite the path matching the `[Route]` description (`http://localhost:8080/api/myControllerPath/1/2/3/4/5`). Any ideas? Are `[Route]` attributes not able to be used in this way with `POST` methods? I don't have this problem with `GET`s.

Comment: Route params need to be enclosed by curly braces in the route

Comment: Wow, facepalm. That fixed it. Thanks @JSteward. Feel free to reply as an answer and I'll mark as correct.